# Элемент по умолчанию в select'е

Tags: html

Каким образом указать выбранный элемент по умолчанию?

Answer (score 1):

```
<option id="d" selected/>
```

UPD1:
Или

```
<head>
    <script>
        function init(){
            document.getElementById('qwe').checked = true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <input type="checkbox" id="qwe" />
</body>
```

*UPD2*:

```
function status($value) { 
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT status_name FROM status"); 
    echo "<select name="status">"; 
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $flag = 1;
            foreach($row as $a){ 
                 if ($flag == 1){
                     echo "<option value=".$a." selected>".$a."</option>";
                     $flag=0;
                 }
                 else
                     echo "<option value=".$a.">".$a."</option>";}
        }
echo "</select>";

}
```

Вот как-то так. Если на скорую руку.

Comment: Вот как сделать, чтоб $value был отмечен как select?

    function status($value) {
        $res = mysql_query("SELECT `status_name` FROM `status`");
        echo "<select name='status'>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            foreach($row as $a) {
                echo "<option value=".$a.">".$a."</option>";

            }
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }

Comment: Какой же он чекед, если он селектед?!

Comment: @knes , все нормально! Я проверил. Свойство для input type="checkbox" - это checked.

Comment: Вот так можно:  

    <input type="checkbox" id="qw1e" checked />

Comment: @Антон Мухин вы вопрос читали?О_о<br>
Причем тут чекбокс?

Comment: @AlexWindHope Ага. На всякий случай сразу два примера привел. Мне не трудно было.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то надо так

```
<select name="имя">
    <option disabled>Выберите пункт</option>  //Заблокированный, если нужен
    <option value="пункт1">пункт1</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="пункт2">пункт2</option>//Пункт поумолчанию                     
    <option value="пункт3">пункт3</option>                     атрибутом "selected "
    <option value="пункт4">пункт4</option>
</select>
```